# How to retriev tag information via sql

Tags: tags

I am working on a report and part of the requirement is to have pull the list of tags per individuals, households and organizations.
I was able to pull the groups by using civicrm_group_contact and civicrm_group tables and join by id. I see a table in civi called civicrm_tag, it contains list of tags but I don't know how to connect it with the associated records or identify the people assigned to theses tags.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Edward

Answer (score 2):

The table is `civicrm_entity_tag`; make sure you use a WHERE or JOIN to ensure that entity_table = 'civicrm_contact'.

Comment: Hi Jon,Thanks you Jon, Please what is the consequence of not specifying civicrm contact in the where clause? Does it then provide the pull tages for all other modules in civi such as civicontribute, event, campaign, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are only pulling the list of tags per individual.., check out the search builder; /civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1